# Cancel a form's request after it was submitted

Tags: javascript, forms, post

Is it possible to cancel the (POST) request made by a form **after** it was submitted?

I am streaming* large amounts of data from a database straight to the client for download (i.e. `Content-Disposition: attachment;`). In order to do this, I create a temporary form and submit it (so that I can send request parameters in the body and still have the browser download the response as a file).

```
var form = document.createElement('form');
form.setAttribute('method', 'post');
form.setAttribute('action', '/query/stream');

var paramElement = document.createElement('input');
paramElement.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
paramElement.setAttribute('name', 'jsonParams');
paramElement.setAttribute('value', JSON.stringify(reqParams));

form.appendChild(paramElement);

document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
document.body.removeChild(form);
```

However, it can take up to a minute after submitting for the download to start (while the data retrieves the data). I'd like the user to be able to cancel the request after submitting. Is this possible?

In case it's useful, the client-side is AngularJS and the server-side is Node.js.

**I'm streaming because creating a temporary file on the server is non-trivial and I can't send the data via a non-streaming response because the data is too large to keep in server memory.*

### Update

I can't use AJAX because I'm streaming straight to a file download. An AJAX call would require that the data be completely downloaded (into memory) before firing any `load` event. This would lead to memory problems on the client-side.

Comment: Have you considered using websockets?

Comment: You may be able to trigger a page redirect to chop off the socket, though I'd expect you may get inconsistent results with this approach.  A better route may be to post the data with ajax (or websockets), and set a time out on the connection.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets I'm not too familiar with Websockets. Taking into account that I can't use AJAX-like solutions (see update in question), would Websockets still work? If so, any pointers on how to start?

Comment: Yes, websockets would help with that. You could have one socket running the binary datatransfer whilst a second socket is usedfor status updates etc and can be used to terminate the active dataflow. My personal preference is to code sockets in java because of the ease of threading and the collections types available